# Issues deleting / inserting vertex in a graph

Tags: c, graph

I'm trying to implement graph in C using an array to store vertices and an adjacency matrix to store edges.

Vertices are all "named", name is their index in an array. For example if I add vertex by giving it the index "2" it will be put in the third position of the array so that if I want to check if two vertices are adjacent in the matrix it could be done in O(1).

If the array become full I will do a realloc incrementing its size so that every add is successful.

Well, there are some problems.

- What if I delete a node? There will be unused space in the array, so it's a waste of memory. (I can't shift all other vertices because it can happen that a vertex named "10" will be moved in a different position, so if I want to check adjacent of the node "10" the result will be adjacents of another node)
- What if I add a node named "50" and the array length is only 10? I have to allocate an array of at least 51 position and there will be a lot of unused space.

Do you have any tips or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array. Use a double-linked list. That way, you can add and delete nodes at will.

Here's a rough example:

```
typedef struct node {
    int vertex;
    node prev;
    node next;
} *node;

node *global;

void insert_node(node a)
{
    global->next = a;
    global->next->vertex = global->vertex + 10;
    global->next->prev = global;
    global = global->next;
}

void delete_node(node b)
{
    while( global->prev )
        global = global->prev;
    while( global != b )
        global = global->next;

    global->prev->next = global->next;
    global->next->prev = global->prev;

    while( global->next )
        global = global->next;

    free(b);
}

node create_node(void)
{
    node ret;
    ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
    memset(ret, 0, sizeof(*ret));
    insert_node(ret);
    return global;
}
```